# Different between android style Widget.Button and Widget.Button.Inset

Tags: button, android-widget

I'm trying to use one of the existing Widget.Button styles but I see two different styles that look the same, but I'm sure there's a reason why they are made distinct.  Can anyone explain the difference between the Widget.Button style versus the Widget.Button.Inset style, or at least an application where I would use one style over the other?

Thanks.

MB

Answer (score 1):

The Widget.Button.Inset has a different background image and some attributes are not set.

The following is taken from Android's default [styles.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD) file:

```
<style name="Widget.Button">
     <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
     <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
     <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
     <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
     <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
 </style>

 <style name="Widget.Button.Inset">
     <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/button_inset</item>
 </style>
```

You can read more about Android styles and themes at [Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).